# Data matching between 2 layers which do not overlap

Tags: qgis, vector, geometry, qgis-processing

I would like to know how a vector layer can takes attributes of a field, of another vector layer which is not overlapping.

For example, there are 2 vector layers, test_1 (2 records A,B) and test_2 (3 records 1,2,3), and i should have as output, the layer test_1 with the same route, but composed/separated by 3 records as test_2, with the additional field ID (1,2,3) moved to the attribute table of test_1.

This geometry process should be as precise as possible.

Can I do this using QGIS geoprocessing tools?

[image]
[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q134n.jpg)
[image]

[image]
[image][image]

---

Using "Join Attributes by Nearest" doesn't work because the records continue to begins and ends in the same points of Test_1. I should have Test_1 divided in 3 records, for example at the transects of Test_2; with 1,2,3 in the attribute table. Look at the pic.

[image]

I'm thinking to use this flow ("Transect" of Test_2 -> "Split by lines" of Test_1 from transect -> "Join Attributes by Nearest" -> "Group geometries" of Test_1 from ID), but this is not accurate when a meet an intersection of lines because the transects create much confusion.

Comment: Did you try 'join attributes by nearest'?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "Join Attributes by Nearest" tool from the processing toolbox.
As you can see on the picture you will need two import layers set a maximum nearest neighbor and if needed a maximum distance.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Using only "Join Attributes by Nearest" tool doesn't work because the geometries of test_1 begins and ends in the same points. I'd like to have test_1 divided in 3 parts corresponding to the transects from the test_2 vertexes. Test_1 should have 3 records divided in the transect intersection and having 1,2,3 in the attribute table. I'm thinking to use this flow ("transect" Test_2 -> "split with lines" Test_1 -> "join attributes by nearest" -> "group geometries" from ID Test_1) but this approach is not accurate especially when i meet an intersection of lines. Thank You!